# Unable to make TextView visible

Tags: android

Am trying to set the textview element visible when I click a button. I have set TextView to invisible and Button in this way:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="Solution" />
```

Now for setting the textview to visible after clicking the button I have written the following java code:

```
Button sl;
TextView tv;
sl=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
sl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

But after clicking the button the textview box is not getting displayed.

**EDIT**:
TOTAL CODE:

```
package com.example.aptitude;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuesOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener,OnClickListener{

    RadioGroup rg;
    Button bt,sl;
    TextView tv;
    Bundle b;
    Intent in;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.q1);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        sl=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        sl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        b=new Bundle();
        in=new Intent("com.example.aptitude.TWO");
        int n=0;

        switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.radio0:
                n=0;
                b.putInt("key", n);
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                n=0;
                b.putInt("key", n);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                n=0;
                b.putInt("key", n);
                break;
            case R.id.radio3:
                n++;
                b.putInt("key", n);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        in.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(in);
    }


}
```

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="CORPULENT" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Lean" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gaunt" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Emaciated" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Obese" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:text="Solution" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not? post your layout and code

Comment: Done posted the full code.

Comment: Is it going inside `onClick`? Put a line `system.out.println("In methpd");` and check if you see it in logcat

Comment: got the Problem remove this  android:layout_marginTop="67dp" from text view

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot how do you know? will it not depend on the screen size

Comment: @Anuraag remove `android:visibility="gone"` for testing. run the app and check whether the textview is visible on the screen.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes You are right it Depends on Screen. But For testing He can remove and Check. May he executing in small size emulator

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot i don't see much of a problem. Should work fine

Comment: @Raghunandan I told You that problem of Margin. TextView going Out of Screen

Comment: Shabbir Dhangot you are right...it was because of the margin...textview was not visible as it was a small screen...adjusting margin-top was the solution. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
android:text="TextView"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

Try this

Comment: developer.android.com/reference/android/view/…. invisible Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it). So what is the difference

Comment: remove margin I think Your TextView Overlaping

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot maybe, but if he is using a Vertical `LinerarLayout` all the content will be pushed down

Comment: @blackbelt This May possible

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot but you have `android:layout_marginTop="67dp"` in your post

Comment: @blackbelt You saw the XML problem of MarginTop 67dp

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but there may be a problem about positioning the items. If you are using these items in RelativeLayout, the button appears in front of the textview so you don't see it.

And also even if the textview is INVISIBLE, you should see a blank space in the place of your textview.

Comment: ya am using relative view...posted the full code...please check it once.

Comment: Then just change the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. This should work

Answer (score 1):

Try it like below. Problem might be is your text-view is out of the area of your screen because of `android:layout_marginTop="67dp"` i am not sure but this is just what i guess so remove that line and try your code something like below.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:text="Solution" />
```

and in Java.

```
Button b1;
TextView tv;
sl=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility. `invisible` Not displayed, but taken into account during layout (space is left for it). So what is the difference. `gone` makes it  Completely hidden, as if the view had not been added.

Comment: @Raghunandan, There is no difference, but What i suppose in this case is is `android:layout_marginTop="67dp"` this property is making his text-view out of the screen. I am not sure this just what i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the parent of the TextView and the Button is a LinearLayout and not a RelativeLayout or FrameLayout, or set the visibility of the Button as well:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    sl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `onClick` implementation in your code:

Firstly, you have set `onClickListener` to button like:

```
sl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

And you have also implemented `OnClickListener` like:

```
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    in.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Try using just one method of two, and put the code for visibility in that. I think that should work fine.

Comment: `bt.setOnClickListener(this);` and this  `sl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`